# Staf Copy on same Machine : Error registering with STAF, RC: 10

Tags: linux, staf

I want to copy a file from one directory to another directory. For doing this I am using `staf` which gets invoked in one php script, but getting below error, even if I run `staf` command like below

```
[root@balveer ConfigManagement_phps]# /usr/local/staf/bin/staf local FS COPY FILE /prd/mdp/Config_Manager/Configuration_files/configfiles/PCEF1/pcef.conf tomachine 172.19.13.53 todirectory /prd/mdp/Config_Manager/Configuration_files/updatedconfigs/
Error registering with STAF, RC: 10
```

At the time of starting `staf`, it says staf initialized

Ping test also gives same error

```
[root@balveer bin]# STAF LOCAL PING PING

Error registering with STAF, RC: 10
```

I am running staf version 3.4.11 on RHEL 6.3

Comment: After you get this error, what is the result of `echo $?`

Comment: Hi Burhan ... output is 0

Comment: From the [error codes list](http://staf.sourceforge.net/current2x/STAFRC.htm) RC: 10 means that the OS returned an error; so the problem is not with STAF. There is even a [faq entry](http://staf.sourceforge.net/current/STAFFAQ.htm#d0e1786) specifically for RC 10.

Comment: Yes i checked it but not getting any clue on this. All files are present at respective paths also.

Comment: @Burhan .. the problem is solved. I added 1 config file at /etc/ld.so.conf.d/staf.conf (Content : /usr/local/staf/lib ) and then did ldconfig . Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You should add the resolution as an answer (its okay to [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) with some more details (perhaps how did you realize the problem?) and then accept your own answer. This way the question will be closed and anyone else who runs into it will know what how you resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I did following :

```
$ echo "/usr/local/staf/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/staf.conf
$ ldconfig
```

Basically, adding STAF library path in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/staf.conf`